# How to restrict only one client to access a file at a time locally in Node js

Tags: node.js, file, locking, fs

I'm creating a local data store in  node js and it will create a json file in a specific location
I want that file to be used by only one client at any given time if another client tries to access the same file then it should throw error, everything happens locally in the computer

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to implement a lock. If you don't know what it is I'd recommend reading about it.

If it's just a pet project, create an object that's responsible for opening and closing a file. It can have some internal state that indicates if file is currently used.